# How to get japanese wiki link from my english wiki link?

Tags: php, wikipedia-api

Task: We have wikipedia English page and need to retrieve the same page address in Japanese.

suggested to parse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini 4wd?action=raw results (there are other languages links in the bottom), but this way is too inefficient. Are there any other ways is the one real option?

We found some API in Wiki that seems fine for single word. but for two words like - Kamen rider, mini 4wd ... it doesn't work.

My code is not working

```
    $url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&llprop=url&lllang=ja&titles=Kamen rider';
    $url = rawurldecode(urlencode($url));
    echo $url;
    // outputs: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&llprop=url&lllang=ru&titles=Mini+4wd

    // and then the rest your logic whatever it is the rest
    $header[] = "Accept: application/json";
    $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
     /* echo '<pre>';
     print_r($response);
     echo '</pre>'; */

    exit;
```

Comment: Why do you specify `lllang=ru` if you're looking for japanese links? Also, the `titles` field is case-sensitive, and querying for `Mini 4wd` and `Mini 4WD` won't return the same results

Comment: Hi swordofpain,I replaced lllang=ja also not working.

Comment: You added capitalization? [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&llprop=url&lllang=ja&titles=Mini%204WD) looks fine to me...

Comment: @suresh your code works fine in my current environment. maybe your curl isn't setup right

Comment: @suresh and check [**here**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qhBF9z). if it still doesn't work. alternatively, you could use `file_get_contents()`

Comment: [It sure seems to work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sEnbBL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try this code it works. Your **$keywords = 'Mini 4wd';**

```
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&llprop=url&lllang=ja&titles='.$keywords.'&redirects=';

$url1 = rawurldecode(urlencode($url));
$ch = curl_init();
// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$exec = explode('"url":"',$output);
$exe = explode('",',$exec[1]);
$URL = $exe[0];
```

Output :

```
<p>Wikipedia Help here as <a href="<?php echo $URL;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $URL;?></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two words doesn't work because its not properly formatted. `Kamen<space>rider` and `mini<space>4wd` has spaces. You need it to be converted first. Consider this example:

```
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&llprop=url&lllang=ru&titles=Mini 4wd';
$url = rawurldecode(urlencode($url));
echo $url;
// outputs: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&format=json&lllimit=100&llprop=url&lllang=ru&titles=Mini+4wd

// and then the rest your logic whatever it is the rest
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$contents = json_decode($contents, true);
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($contents);
// echo '</pre>';
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ISvmg9)

Comment: More generally, your keyword needs to be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urlencoding), especially for spaces as you noticed, but also ampersands (`&`), question marks (`?`) and hash signs (`#`). PHP has a nice [`urlencode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for that

Comment: Hi kevinabelita,It does not return url. I need https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx this kind of url from json response

Comment: hello @suresh kindly check this [**fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ISvmg9) and try to modify it to fit to yours

Comment: Hi kevinabelita, actually i did those steps but i cant get the url link this is my problem that's why i'm asking kindly guide me

Comment: @suresh maybe you could also post your current code and **edit** your question and let us see your work as i will have no clue on how you are doing it :)

Comment: @suresh maybe you could also utilize a fiddle like this one